# Сообщение пришло на проверку два раза

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Вот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879378/180398 (но его скоро удалят, на всякий случай ссылка еще и на вопрос: [Что такое BoringSSL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878664/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-boringssl)).

Вчера этот вопрос попался мне на проверке, я нажал "рекомендовать удаление", сегодня он мне попался во второй раз, под ним даже мой комментарий виден:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если посмотреть историю, то я там один раз упомянут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второй раз выбрали тот же вариант? Это точно не был аудит?

Comment: Первый раз выбрал "Удалить"/"Не является ответом на вопрос", второй раз - "Удалить"/"Комментарии не требуются". Не аудит (оба раза).

Comment: А очереди одинаковые были? Есть подозрение, что это может быть связано с [новой привилегией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). У Вас как раз 2к репутации настало.

Comment: Хотя смотрю это превышение 2к уже давно было. Действительно, странно.

Comment: У меня тоже два раза всплывал. По [временной шкале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/879378/timeline) вроде и не проверялся или проверка не закончена. Странно.

Comment: Есть на MSE [нечто подобное](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251176/339911), но без ссылок и картинок.